# PHP сравнить по началу строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки, сравнение

Есть строка:
**/test/app/id100**
Как проверить есть ли в строке **"/test/app/id[число]"** тогда **true** иначе **false**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и проверить

```
if (preg_match('#^/test/app/id\d+#', $foo) === 1) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Comment: Только лучше `\d+` заменить на `[1-9]\d+` чтоб исключить невалидные идешки типа `/id000001`, но эт только если у вас не бывает идешек с ведущими нулями.

Comment: начало обозначили дак и конец `$` обозначить бы не мешало мб?

Comment: @teran в вопросе просят проверить паттерн начала строки, а не всю целиком

Comment: да, только что сам заметил :)

Comment: @Lexx918 спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Регулярочкой

```
$uri = '/test/app/id100';

echo preg_match('~id\d+$~', $uri) ? 'TRUE': 'FALSE'; // TRUE
```

Comment: сработает для `blabla_id100_blabla` не?

Comment: не учитывается совпадение по началу строки

Comment: @teran, подправил шаблон. Спасибо

Comment: @Lexx918, должно быть точное соответствие подстроке "/test/app/" ?

Comment: @Эдуард да, если внимательно перечитать название вопроса

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо

Comment: @user3608884 если вам подошёл мой вариант, то отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

Символьный класс `\d` соответствует одной цифер, квантификатор `+` указывает, что цифр должно быть несколько. Само регулярное выражение обрамляется точками с запятыми, чтобы не экранировать слеши. Функция **preg_match** возвращает 1, если строка подходит или 0 в противном случае.

```
if (preg_match(";/test/app/id\d+;", "/test/app/id100")) {
    ...
}
```